# How to convert unix timestamp (long) to datetime in pyspark sql?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In pyspark sql, I have unix timestamp column that is a long - I tried using the following but the output was not correct.

```
from_unixtime(col("firstAvailableDateTimeUnix"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

[from_unixtime output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR86C.png)

Comment: first you need <value in col>/1000

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is casting and then use `date_format` to format your timestamp:

```
date_format(col("firstAvailableDateTimeUnix").cast('timestamp'), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = Seq(1651484635297L).toDF("firstAvailableDateTimeUnix").withColumn("goodDate",
from_unixtime(col("firstAvailableDateTimeUnix")/1000, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
)

df.show(false)
//    +--------------------------+-------------------+
//    |firstAvailableDateTimeUnix|goodDate           |
//    +--------------------------+-------------------+
//    |1651484635297             |2022-05-02 12:43:55|
//    +--------------------------+-------------------+
```